# Show a message-box when the database is empty

Tags: c#, sql, database, forms, messagebox

thanks for viewing my question. Basically, when the user clicks on a button, it will either say one of the following in a message box based on what the database has: Your holiday has been authorised, your holiday has been declined or your holiday request has been sent.

I want it so that when the user clicks on the button and there isn't any data in the database because the user hasn't sent a holiday request, to receive a message box saying that they haven't booked an holiday.

Here's my code:

```
            private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Login"];
        SundownDatabaseEntities6 db = new SundownDatabaseEntities6();
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Login)f).idTb.Text);

        var getrecords = db.Holidays.Where(a => a.Id == id).ToList();

            foreach (var record in getrecords)
            {
                if (record.YesOrNo == "yes")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The manager has accepted your holiday (From " + record.Datefrom + " - " + record.Dateto + ").");
                }
                else if (record.YesOrNo == "no")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The manager has declined your holiday request (" + record.Datefrom + " - " + record.Dateto + ").");
                }
                else if (record.YesOrNo == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your holiday request (" + record.Datefrom + " - " + record.Dateto + ") has been sent.\nWaiting for manager to authorise it...");
                }
                else if (record != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have not booked an holiday.");
            }
            }
        }
```

Problem is on the last bit of the code, the 'else if(record != null)' doesn't check if the database is empty. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Before the loop, you can check `if (!db.Holidays.Any(a => a.Id == id))` and show the *"no holiday requested"* message and return wothout entering the loop.

Comment: You have to check for 'record' being number before you check for record.YesOrNo.  If record is null, then you will get an exception on record.YesOrNo.  You have no exception handler so the exception is jumping elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `getrecords.Count()`

```
var getrecords = db.Holidays.Where(a => a.Id == id).ToList();
if (getrecords.Count() == 0) 
{
 //  ... here your logic
}
```

Or

```
if (!db.Holidays.Any ())
```

Because it won't go to `foreach`  if `getrecords` is empty.